# Non-Blocking UDP-Client Receive Thread-Safe Call

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, udp, nonblocking

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for ages. I have tried many things, including BeginReceive(), but all to no avail. There must be a way to do this, make a UDP-Client receive call that is non blocking AND thread safe. I am trying to receive a message and write it to a Rich Text Box.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool contfunctioning = true; public bool changedsplay = false;
        public string enteredchats, msg, chatstring, Chats;

        UdpClient subscriber = new UdpClient(8899);
        UdpClient publisher = new UdpClient("230.0.0.100", 8898);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string ConnectIPAddress;
            ConnectIPAddress = txtboxIP.Text;
            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(ConnectIPAddress);

            MessageBox.Show("Subscribing to chat server on " + ConnectIPAddress + ".", ConnectIPAddress);

            EndPoint ep = null;

            // This is where The UDPClient subscriber needs to Begin.Receive()


        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enteredchats = txtboxUsr.Text + " " + txtboxentertxt.Text;
            txtboxentertxt.Clear();

            msg = String.Format(enteredchats);
            sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            publisher.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
        }

    }
}
```

Enough code, yes? 
Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: How have you tried `BeginReceive`? It's thread-safe if you use it correctly.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Using BeginReceive would work perfectly here.

Comment: Is it me or does the code snippet contain BeginReceive somewhere?

Comment: It does not contain BeginReceive(), as I stated in my question I tried it and it did not work. The tutorials I found for it were not extremely descriptive, if someone could show me in an answer how to do it in this case that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using a Timer() allowed me to circumvent this problem.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace Chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public bool contfunctioning = true; public bool changedsplay = false; public bool setupntwrk = false;
        public string enteredchats, msg, chatstring, Chats, lastchatstring;

        UdpClient subscriber = new UdpClient(8899);
        UdpClient publisher = new UdpClient("230.0.0.100", 8898);

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1use = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread rcvchats = new Thread(ReceiveChats);
            rcvchats.Start();

            timer1use.Interval = 1000;
            timer1use.Start();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enteredchats = txtboxUsr.Text + ": " + txtboxentertxt.Text;
            txtboxentertxt.Clear();

            msg = String.Format(enteredchats);
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            publisher.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chatstring != lastchatstring)
            dsplay.AppendText("\r\n" + chatstring);

            lastchatstring = chatstring;


        }

        public void ReceiveChats()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (setupntwrk == false)
                {
                    string ConnectIPAddress;
                    ConnectIPAddress = txtboxIP.Text;
                    IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(ConnectIPAddress);
                    MessageBox.Show("Subscribing to chat server on " + ConnectIPAddress + ".", ConnectIPAddress);
                    subscriber.JoinMulticastGroup(addr);

                    setupntwrk = true;
                }

                IPEndPoint ep = null;
                chatstring = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(subscriber.Receive(ref ep));

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }

        private void btnHost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process starthost = new Process();
            starthost.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ChatServ.exe";
            starthost.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Its legal to answer my own question, in fact, there happens to be a badge for it.